# are there any standard proof formats?

Tags: proof-assistant

I would like to know if there are any proof formats which is used to exchange proofs among proof assistants. I realize different proof assistants use different foundations but for those that have the same or similar foundations are there any standard formats?

Comment: https://jesper.sikanda.be/files/AIMXXXI-presentation.pdf I'll let qualified people give a more substantial answer.

Comment: Here's a related question: [_Is there a way to automatically translate proofs from one proof assistant to another?_](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/79)

Comment: This is also related: [Does there exists a logical format so that my app can export in that format, and the existing popular proof assistants can take it as input?](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/1681)

Comment: @jude Do either of these two linked questions answer your question?  If so we can mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @JasonRute They were informative and enough for my needs so I dont mind it being marked as duplicate. But imho i dont think they are definitive enough (if at all there is a definitive answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [OpenTheory system](https://www.gilith.com/opentheory/) has a standard format for the core HOL logics supported by HOL Light, HOL4, ProofPower and HOL Zero.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [Metamath Zero](https://github.com/digama0/mm0) by Mario Carneiro

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [TPTP](https://www.tptp.org/) format for theorem prover problems. It acts as a pretty standard format for stating results in a "prover independent" manner.